# Java writing to File or System.out

Tags: java

I need to write characters to a file or to standard output. And I am curious if it could be done with one method.

Now I have something like this:

```
OutputStream out;    
if(toConsole)
   out = System.out;
else
   out = new FileOutputStream(file);

write(out);
}
void write (OutputStream str){
 ....
 str.write(string);
```

But it is a problem that I am using (in case when "str" is System.out) write instead print? 
(print java doc: "string's characters are converted into bytes according to the platform's default character encoding")
In case if I would use PrintWriter(or PrintStream) as a parameter then i cannot use BufferedWriter and writing to the file would be slower.

It is possible to use a same code (and same methods) for writing to a file and to System.out?
(This is for my school project so I want it to be a "pure" and fully correct)

Comment: What you could do is redirect the stdout to your own Printsteeam, as demonstrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945537/how-to-set-output-stream-to-textarea/12945678#12945678), which actually demonstrates a proxy approach, which allows you to redirect the output to somewhere else but also still have it appear in the console. I've used this approach to a capture output of programs that didn't included logging

Comment: You can easily wrap a PrintWriter/PrintStream/etc around a BufferedWriter as shown in [the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) but personally I wouldn't worry about it either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to accomplish, is to treat the fileoutput and the consoleoutput the same. This is possible, because `System.out` is a [`PrintStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html), and you can create a `PrintStream` for a file like this

```
new PrintStream(yourFile)
```

or insert a `BufferedOutputStream` in between

```
new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(yourFile))).
```

Note that this is **not needed**, because `PrintStream` does [buffer its output itself](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#PrintStream%28java.io.File%29).

I would create a variable (global or not), representing the current output.
This might be a `PrintStream`, either `System.out`, or a `PrintStream` around a `FileOutputStream`, whatever you desire. You would then pass this stream to the write method or call the print methods on it directly.

The advantage is that you can easily switch this without much code modification, you can redirect it wherever you wan't. It's no problem to redirect it to a file *and* `System.out`! You wouldn't get that *pure* flexibility with the way you're writing the method currently.

You *could* (not saying you should), also redirect `System.out` directly, using [`System.setOut`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut%28java.io.PrintStream%29). This however is bad style, because it is quite uncommon and might confuse everyone else, if they have not seen the call to `System.setOut`.

Answer (score 0):

System.out is an object of type PrintStream. So yes, you can write to 
System.out and/or to another file using exactly the same methods. Just  
construct a PrintStream object and direct it to your file. So declare  
your out variable as PrintStream to start with.

See also:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html