# how giving the user error messages?

Tags: java, swing, message

I wrote a little java tool with a GUI, that needs a source path (e.g. Music folder) and a destination path (e.g. USB device) entered by the user.

If the user selects a drive that is not available (e.g. select USB device and unplug it afterwards from the PC) I need to output a error message, like "device E:\ not available".

I would like to know, what is a good or professional way to create and show messages in a JFrame GUI? Show messages in a jTextArea? Via Popup?

Right now, I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945537/how-to-set-output-stream-to-textarea) solution from  Joffrey, but it show the whole error output from the console - what a usual user not understands.
[How to set output stream to TextArea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945537/how-to-set-output-stream-to-textarea)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind to use 3rd party libraries, i recommend to use [JXErrorPane](http://javadoc.geotoolkit.org/external/swingx/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXErrorPane.html) by [swingX](https://swingx.java.net/) otherwise you can use a simple [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) that is very powerful and customizable.

Comment: Thank you, I think I will start with JOptionPane.

Answer (score 1):

As nachokk recommended for display the JXErrorPane is very useful to be able to show a human readable message to a user and still have the stack trace accessible.

The other side will be translation of an `exception` into a message that a user understands.  You will need to possibly add additional catch statements that handle each Exception that should generate a different message to the user.

The message text from some exceptions is normally not clear enough on its own.  In your app a "File Not Found" message would need to explain to the user if it is the destination or source path.

Answer (score 1):

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(myPanel,
                "Something went wrong",
                "Error!",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```