# How to display Dependency tree representation in standard output in to a Java Frame

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, dependencies

I have generated a dependency representation of given sentence using the following code.

```
SemanticGraph dependencies =     sentence.get(CollapsedCCProcessedDependenciesAnnotation.class);
System.out.println(dependencies);
```

I am getting the desired output in the standard output window. Now I want to redirect this output into a JFrame form (NetBeans). Is it Possible? Which form can be used and What is the code? Please help

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26270382/how-to-take-terminal-results-and-set-a-jtextarea-to-read-the-terminal/26270641#26270641)?