# Console out.print in JTextArea

Tags: java, jtextarea, stringstream, println

I have some silly problem. I need to `"out.print"` the results to a `JTextArea` just as it does with a console:

```
for (int m=0;  m<mieszkanie.length;  m++) {
    boolean test = false;
    String test1 = mieszkanie[m];
    for (int n=0;n<mieszkanieID.length;n++) {
        String test2 = mieszkanieID[n];
        if (test1.equals(test2)){
            test = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (test==false) {
        System.out.println(test1);
        //JTextArea = "poleStatusu"
    }
}
```

With `System.out.println()` it of course prints every single "false", but when I use 
`poleStatusu.setText(test1)` it just prints the last `"false"`.

What I need is just something to print every "false" in the `poleStatusu` text area - it doesn't matter if it's going to connect the Strings or to make `JTextArea` as a console. I know these methods exist, but I'm not sure how to implement them correctly.

Comment: You need to use `JTextArea#append` or you could use something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945537/how-to-set-output-stream-to-textarea/12945678#12945678) which redirects the `System.out` through the `JTextArea`

Answer (score 1):

First of all you must create an object of `JTextArea`.
Then you can set the text by `append` method.
Like this:

```
JTextArea jText = new JTextArea(10, 30);
jText.append("some text");
```