# How to print the console output to the JTextArea?

Tags: java, mongodb, console, jframe, jtextarea

Following is my java code :

Can someone please suggest how to print the same on `JTextArea`?

```
 DBCursor cursor = coll.find();

 int i=1;
 while (cursor.hasNext())
 {
    System.out.println("Inserted Document: "+i);
    System.out.println(cursor.next()); // i want to print this into jtextarea
    i++;
 }
```

Comment: I'd like to close this question with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945537/how-to-set-output-stream-to-textarea/12945678#12945678), but that might be a little over kill for your needs

Answer (score 0):

You can add the output to textarea as follows:

```
textarea.append(""+cursor.next());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `JTextArea.setText(String)` and `JTextArea.append(String)` to do this.

`setText` replaces the text in the text area. `append` adds a `string` to the end of the existing text.