# How to properly decode and encode characters from JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, encoding, stream

I have a program that works on a console, and i want to make a custom console for it. Current command line interface can be started with a method that takes an InputStream and PrintStream as arguments.

I have two text areas (JTextArea), one of which i want to use for input and the other one for output. I've extended InputStream and OutputStreams to provide streams to my starting method:

```
    public class ConsoleInputStream extends InputStream implements KeyListener {

    private BlockingDeque<Integer> mBuffer = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();
    private JTextArea mJTextArea;

    public ConsoleInputStream(JTextArea JTextArea) {
        mJTextArea = JTextArea;
        mJTextArea.addKeyListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyChar();
        char c = (char) key;
        mBuffer.add(key);
    }

    @Override
    public int read() {
        try {
            char c = (char) (int) mBuffer.take();

            if(c == '\n')
                mJTextArea.setText("");

            return c;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) {
        if (b == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        } else if (off < 0 || len < 0 || len > b.length - off) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        } else if (len == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        int c = read();
        if (c == -1) {
            return -1;
        }
        b[off] = (byte)c;

        int i = 1;
        try {
            for (; i < len && available() > 0 ; i++) {
                c = read();
                if (c == -1) {
                    break;
                }
                b[off + i] = (byte)c;
            }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
        return i;

    }
}
```

And for the output:

```
    public class ConsoleOutputStream extends OutputStream {

    private JTextArea mJTextArea;

    public ConsoleOutputStream(JTextArea JTextArea) {
        mJTextArea = JTextArea;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        mJTextArea.append(String.valueOf((char) b));
    }
}
```

Start the program:

```
 CommandInterface.get().start(ui.getConsoleIn(), new PrintStream(ui.getConsoleOut()));
```

(ui is an instance of a class that extends JFrame, the getConsoleIn() and getConsoleOut() return an instance of ConsoleInputStream and ConsoleOutputStream)

Inside of which i use scanner to read the input stream:

```
public void start(InputStream inputStream, PrintStream outputStream){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8");

    while (true){
        String[] input = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");

        if(input[0].equals("exit"))
            break;

        Command command = mCommands.get(input[0]);
        if(command == null){
            displayErrorMessage("No such command", outputStream);
            continue;
        }

        List<String> flags = new LinkedList<>();
        List<String> params = new LinkedList<>();

        for(String s : Arrays.copyOfRange(input, 1, input.length)){
            if(s.charAt(0) == '/')
                flags.add(s.substring(1));
            else
                params.add(s);
        }

        command.execute(outputStream, flags, params);
    }

}
```

And this works fine, untill I try to use the local characters: ś ć ó ż ź etc.

I have tried many diffrent solutions, none worked for me. Then I tried to figure it out myself. Every time I read a char I also printed it to standard output (my IDE), which I know can display those characters correctly. I found out that they are being read correctly, but thre are  characters (UTF-8 65535) inbetween them (not in a regular pattern but in pairs), for reasons that are unclear to me. I also tried:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true){
          ui.getConsoleOut().write(scanner.nextLine().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        }
```

with diffrent charsets, but couldn't get them do display correctly.

What is the proper way to display those (and other UTF-8) characters?

Comment: What _actually_ happened when you tried to use "ś ć ó ż ź etc"?

Comment: When I print them directly (from the last code example) with UTF-8, the output is: ￅﾛ ￄﾇ ￃﾳ ￅﾼ ￅﾺ etc

Comment: Does `CommandInterface.get().start` accept an `InputStream` and a `PrintStream`? Does `ui.getConsoleIn()` return a `ConsoleInputStream`? And what does the `new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8");` got to do with all this?

Comment: Yes, the CommandInterface.get().start is the method that starts the command line interface I wrote about at the beginning. ui.getConsoleIn() return a ConsoleInputStream. The scanner is used to read an input (a command), and after its execution, output is written to the PrintStream that was passed to CommandInterface.get().start method. Sorry for the lack of details, i'll add more code to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you have done anything else wrong, but I know you at least need to fix this:

`read` and `write` methods don't work with *characters*, they work with *bytes*. One character != one byte.

I'm talking about these:

```
public int read() {
    try {
        char c = (char) (int) mBuffer.take();

        if(c == '\n')
            mJTextArea.setText("");

        return c;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;
}

public void write(int b) throws IOException {
    mJTextArea.append(String.valueOf((char) b));
}
```

You need to turn the `char` into a `byte` array using an encoding that the Scanner can understand. Then turn each of those bytes to unsigned ints, as opposed to treating each character as a single byte.

```
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyChar();
    char c = (char) key;

    if(c == '\n')
        mJTextArea.setText("");

    byte[] byteArray = Character.toString(c).getBytes(StandardCharset.UTF_8);
    for (byte b : byteArray) {
        mBuffer.add(Byte.toUnsignedInt(b));
    }
}

public int read() {
    try {
        byte b = (int) mBuffer.take();
        return b;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return -1;
}
```

For `write`, you can't treat each byte as a single character either. One way to handle this is to subclass `PrintStream` directly. See solution 2 in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17626400/5133585) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

The thing i needed to do, [besides what Sweeper said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61698207/11969776), is to ignore the undefined characters (some keys like ALT or CTRL do not have a char associated with them, so the result is char 65535 - char undefined - )

```
@Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        char c = e.getKeyChar();


        if(c == '\n')
            mJTextArea.setText("");

        if(c == KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED)
            return;

        byte[] byteArray = Character.toString(c).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        for (byte b : byteArray) {
            mBuffer.add(Byte.toUnsignedInt(b));
        }
    }
```